# Blinking and coloring asp.net label control

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-2.0, label, blink

I have a asp.net label control on my webform:

for this label I am setting the text property from code behind:

```
lblOne.Text = "Number of student is: 86 and Number of teacher is: 7";
```

Now I want to do 2 things:

1. Blinking the label.
2. Coloring: "Number of student is:" -
   RED Color "86" :- BLUE

   ```
            "and Number of teacher is:" - RED & 7:- BLUE
   ```

How can I do these things?

Comment: 1994 called, and they want their `<blink>` tag back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you really sure you want that text to blink, the [`<blink>`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blink_element) tag disappeared for a reason :-)

You could set a [ForeColor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.forecolor.aspx) for a label, but only for the complete Label. So what you could do is split that text into two labels, one blue and one red.

A different solution would be to use a [Literal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.literal.aspx) and set the html yourself:

```
Literal1.Text = String.Format("Number of student is: <span style='color:red'>{0}</style> and Number of teacher is: <span style='color:blue'>{1}</span>", student, teacher);
```